# Add a vertical separator between icons and text in a menu

Tags: python, qt, menu, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a question about how to add a separator between icons and text in menu. If you have any ideas, it would be really helpful. Here is exactly what I need to do:

[image: preview].

From a button, open a menu and add separators like in the image.

Comment: Looks more like a Menubar to me [docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmenubar.html). In menu you can add icons and text, usually done through QAction.

Comment: Yes you were right ! it's a QMenubar :) Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you are using a **QMenu()** object you can use **addSeparator()**:

```
menu = QMenu()
add_action = menu.addAction("Add")
menu.addSeparator()
rename_action = menu.addAction("Rename")
```

Comment: I tried but it's only horizontal separator, is it possible to make it vertical. Here is the result I got : http://www.zupmage.eu/i/ZjvAjLmSFx.jpg

Answer (score 1):

If you create the menu yourself by using a `QWidget` it's easy. Just implement the `paintEvent` and draw the lines where you need them.

Comment: In fact, I'm dynamically changing the menu (adding and removing actions) so it will be complicated if I draw lines every time items has been added or removed

Comment: That depends on how generic you implement the drawing .. as the menu will call the `paintEvent` whenever something changes. If you know the number of entries it should be an easy thing to do.